# vite.config.js => Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: vue.js, vite

I created a new repo with $ npm install vue-app and created some test components.

When i run the command $ npm run dev the application starts in localhost port 3000.

I try to add my component in a WP website. When i build the files and add to my theme, i receive the message:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I found some documentation for webpack but not for vite.config.js.

Anyone can help?

vite.config.js

```
// vite.config.js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default {
    plugins: [vue()]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vite-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.2.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "vite": "^2.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which built file are you using on your WP site? You should be using the umd version.

Comment: hey terry, i use the vite.config.js above. with the command "npm run build" (=> vite build).. what does umd version mean?

Comment: Refer to the `build.lib` option: https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-lib, so that you will generate a UMD bundle that you can use on your WP site.

Comment: oh thanks! never did this before do you have an example?

Comment: The readme has all you need to know: https://vitejs.dev/config/#config-file

Comment: the documentation said that the standard format is ['es', 'umd'] so it should be work right? i'm not sure what i have to do if this is already standard value

Comment: i add this line: build: { lib: ['umd'] .. and now i receive this message "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined" but i do not have any path arguements in my app

Comment: ok i solved my problem.. add name in package.json and build: { lib } has two values.. first is "entry" with path to your main.js file and seconds is "name" should be the name of the package.json.. thank you for your help terry!

Answer (score 2):

Your script tag needs `type="module"` if you're using `import`